# how to reslove this C:\inetpub\wwwroot?

Tags: iis, cakephp-3.0, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I am Pretty new in windows IIS server. i have successfully upload cakephp3.0 project.
when i access the website from windows IIS server it displays me following url in every page

```
**C:\inetpub\wwwroot**
```

I have also checked my header.My header part look Like this:-

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
//MY Html Code
```

Even i have checked my all **ctp** but i don't know where th url comes from **C:\inetpub\wwwroot**. Can anyone help me. How to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`C:\inetpub\wwwroot` is the default local path for websites in IIS. You can change it by right clicking on your website > Manage Web Site > Advanced settings > Physical Path:

[image]

Comment: thanks @GôTô for reply actually that url shown in browser in every webpage so we want to hide it from browser? so how we can do that